How to make a non-greedy regex when in multiline mode
I have a text file (latin-1-encoded) with this content:
1
    lorem ipsum 1 ...

1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13
    lorem ipsum 2 ...



1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13
 ...
    H E A D I N G 1
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13

    lorem ipsum 3 ...



where the pattern ^1 indicates the start of new "page".
I now want to use regex (via Python's re module) to match and return the complete page containing "HEADING1" for further processing (expected result):
1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13
 ...
    H E A D I N G 1
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...

My initial approach was to split the content of the file into individual pages (at each ^1), iterate through all pages and test for the presence of "Heading1". IRL, this file is several hundreds of MB in size and this approach takes a long time (~10 seconds).
A regex pattern like this: r'(?m)(H E A D I N G 1[\s\S]*?)(?=^1) returns this:
H E A D I N G 1
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...

This is close and it is much faster (< 0.5 seconds). However, I also need the info above "HEADING1" (between "HEADING1" and directly preceding ^1).
So, I tried a non-greedy match for characters between ^1 and H E A D I N G 1 using .*? in DOTALL mode:
import re

with open('test.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    print(re.search(r'(?ms)(^1.*?H E A D I N G 1[\s\S]*?)(?=^1)', file.read()).group())

The result is a match starting from the very first ^1 (but not the one immidiately before "HEADING1"):
1
    lorem ipsum 1 ...

1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13
    lorem ipsum 2 ...



1                                      OCTOBER  24, 2024  11/27/13
 ...
    H E A D I N G 1
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...

It is not what I wanted (compare to expected reult).
Is there a way how I can get the expected result with one single regex match?

Yes, but I'd recommend doing the extra checks after you get the "pages". You are asking about (?ms)(^1(?:(?!^1).)*?H E A D I N G 1.*?)(?=^1). It can be re-written as (?m)(^1.*(?:\n(?!1).*)*?H E A D I N G 1.*(?:\n(?!1).*)*), btw.

Thanks, I figured that I needed a "Match anything after ^1 but not ^1". However, I did not know how to do it. I was not aware of (?:...).

You were not aware of (?:(?!<exclude_pattern>).)*, a tempered greedy token.

Yep, I saw this term for the first time in your linked answer. :-)

And (?:...) is a non-capturing group. (?!...) is a negative lookahead.
